# When declaring models using classes with Flask-SQLAlchemy, why don't the column variables need "self."?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

For example, take the simple example from the docs [here](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/):

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

I am still new to python classes, so apologies if this is a basic question.

Comment: Because you're defining *class attributes* - note when you use them in an instance method you *do* use `self.`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok I see, so this defines "id", "username", and "email" across all instances of the User class the same way. I guess my next question is, what goes on behind the scenes when you invoke `User(username='susan', email='susan@example.com')`? I assume username isn't being overwritten with a plain string?

Comment: @Nold - sqlalchemy does a lot of metaprogarmming behind the scenes. What happens is not like a standard python class. How its all done is a big question that may be more in the scope of your search engine than stackoverflow.

Comment: @tdelaney I see, thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Flask-SQLAlchemy meta-programming. The class level assignments define a schema. When instances of the class are created, they include some sort of accessor so that a reference to the same name on `self` results in a specific value from the column. This works because sqlalchemy wrote a lot of code to make it happen.

This is not how normal python classes work. You don't need to define attributes at class level for a regular python class. For a regular class, access to `self.bar` checks whether "bar" is local to the instance and then checks whether there is a "bar" on the class. Its like a fallback and it is not required to have one. In either case, setting `self.bar` creates a valid in the instance. As in:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     bar = 1
...     def get_bar(self):
...             return self.bar
...     def set_bar(self, val):
...             self.bar = val
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> print(Foo.bar, foo.bar, foo.get_bar())
1 1 1
>>> foo.set_bar(999)
>>> print(Foo.bar, foo.bar, foo.get_bar())
1 999 999
```

When learning python, the magic behind modules like sqlalchemy, numpy and pandas can leave one with the wrong impression of how the language works.